# A is "Hard", B is "Easier"?

Tags: word-usage

Task A is hard, task B is not that hard, what can I say? Task B is simpler (easier)?

**Because I am afraid it may imply that Task A is simple(easy) but task B is simpler(easier)!!**

> However, these systems are mainly designed to extract structured data such as a product or a service information from complex web pages. **For a simpler task** such as extracting the main article from a news website, the features they provide can be excessive.

Comment: How about a different perspective: "For a less difficult task..."?

Comment: Are you worried that by saying "Task B is simpler than Task A" you will imply that Task A is simple?

Comment: @DavidK yeah....

Comment: I feel your wording says exactly what you meant it to. I would not change it. @DavidK 's answer sums up why you did it correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your comment, it sounds like your main concern is that by saying **"Task B is simpler than Task A"** you will imply that Task A is simple, when it is not.

If you had just gotten done explaining to me how A is complex, then I would not make that conclusion. You have just given me a baseline understanding of how complex Task A is. When you tell me that Task B is simpler or easier, it should not change my perception of Task A. I simply have a reference point to compare to.

However, if you *did* want to say that Task B is simpler than Task A, which is also simple, I would instead say,

> Task B is *even* simpler than Task A.

This says to me that Task A is simple, but Task B is even more so.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing that comes to my mind as the opposite of *hard* meaning "difficult" is *easy*.  *Easily* is the adverb form as @Victor Bazarov says.  (Be careful - *hardly* is *not* an adverb form of *hard*)

*Simple*, and its opposite, *complex*, can refer to the complexity of something - a complex task is usually harder than a simple task, but things other than tasks can be simple/complex.  Whereas *easy/hard* usually only refers to tasks or processes.

Comment: Good, but the question still remains, Hard and easier? I think as @JMB said, it should be "less difficult"

Comment: Sorry, can I say *For a simpler task such as extracting the main article **on** a news website*

Comment: You can.  Especially since you are saying in essence "the software is too complex for just this one task."

Comment: I mainly meant using "on" instead of "from" here

Comment: *On* is okay.  We can tell that "the main article on a news website" is thing extracted, not just "the main article", because in general things are said to be "on" websites.

Answer (score 2):

The adverb *hard* has the antonym *easily*.  The adjective *hard* has an antonym *easy*.  The adjective *simple*'s usual antonyms are *complex*, *complicated*, *elaborate*.

The difference in meaning between *simpler* and *easier* is probably not too drastic for your use.  You can employ either, I think.

Comment: In context, this may be true. But something that is simple is not necessarily easy, and vice versa. Like, if you are overweight, the solution is simple: eat less and exercise more. But as someone who is overweight myself, I can tell you that that's not easy.

Comment: No, "easily" is not the antonym of adverb "hard". When "hard" is an adverb it means "[using a lot of effort](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hard)"; often the best antonym would be "softly" (though this depends on context).

Comment: When talking about a task (or job, activity, effort, etc.), the adjective *hard* has an antonym *easy*.  However, note that the antonym of "hard science" is "*soft* science" (not "easy science").